# C++/Qt String Terminaton in payload

Tags: c++, qt, termination, qbytearray, qiodevice

How does a programmer treat string terminations when it comes to sending strings via an communication interface like IPC,Serial,Ethernet,...

Is it legal to just keep the string termination and hence just append multiple strings within the payload buffer?

Or is there s/t like a rule that says no you don't send string termination via an communication interface?

thanks

Comment: Of course all bytes are raw bytes. Nevertheless, I can tell when a raw byte represents NULL it's my termination character. I need s/t to determine when one strings end and another starts within a buffer.

Comment: I do not see any problem with terminating '\0' if it is not binary data. It is quite frequently used out there. Even I have used it myself quite a bit. So do not worry, all is fine. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not send "strings" over those protocols in the form of as you may think about it. You send raw bytes either in textual or binary form. Think about them in Qt terms as [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html) or [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html).

You will find those classes around the [QIODevice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html) class in the Qt framework which is the base class for any "IO". Then, this base class in QtCore is reimplemented in subclasses like in the QtSerialPort, QtBluetooth, QtNetwork and the like modules.

In general, your question seems to be a bit more protocol oriented, i.e. protocol design. You usually have the terminating character if it is textual data or you could even have a length field instead. The terminating character could also be anything depending on the data, so not just `\0`.

For instance, the protocols we use, it is sometimes '\n', sometimes ';' and what not. It is up to you, but using a dedicated terminating character is well valid and extensively used out there, really.

Naturally, only the length field can be applied when sent in binary mode.

Comment: The protocol was implemented by myself. It shall support mulitple string sending. To know when one string ends and the other starts I need s/t like a marker. This could be a NULL. Does QByteArray get rid of the termination character or does it just turn it into a raw byte as well?

Comment: NULL is not a character. It is a C/C++ thing. In fact, it is 0 (number), not even '\0' if that is what you mean. QByteArray is a byte array as its name indicates, so it interprets the bytes literally. Therefore, it does keep '\0'. But again, that is not NULL. In fact, in some compilers, NULL was implemented as the new nullptr from C++11, oddly or not that oddly enough.

Comment: Sry,my fault, I meant NUL. But if QByteArray keeps it and I send the given raw bytes via an interface and the receiver knows that this a string he can use the NUL to determine the length of the string, right?

Comment: @wanderameise: Not sure what NUL means, but you can use any character.

Answer (score 2):

Communication through any interface, MUST occur according a defined protocol. If there are string termination rules than this will be defined by the protocol. If you're not communicating through an existing protocol than you need to define a protocol (i.e. user-defined protocol). Here you will define how and if you will terminate your strings.